# Delphi - Autenticação DataSnap via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, delphi, autenticação, datasnap

Estou começando agora a utilizar a autenticação no DataSnap.
Estou tentanto acessar os métodos via AJAX e está retornando o erro 401 - Unauthorized.
Minha requisição está da seguinte maneira:

```
$.ajax({
        username: login,
        password: pass,
        async : false,
        cache: "false",
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        url: url,
        success: function(data){...}
```

Fiz isso seguindo [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459148/passing-datasnap-authentication-credentials-with-jquery-and-ajax) pergunta, onde a única diferença é que não estou utilizando `jsonp`.

Quando acesso pelo browser, é exibido uma caixa para inserção do usuário e da senha, quando insiro as credenciais me permite continuar.
Alguém sabe como resolver?

***EDIT 1***
Tambem já tentei fazer a requisição utilizando:

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', makeBaseAuth(login, pass));
    }
```

No lugar de `username` e `password`.

Comment: Qual delphi você está usando e como você criou o projeto DataSnap para começar a funcionar como WebService, foi a partir do DataSnap REST ou DataSnap Server?

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf Estou usando do Delphi XE7, foi criado como DataSnao REST, e marquei a opção Authentication ao criá-lo. Já setei o método OnAuthentication e os UserRoles. Testando no navegador ou no ServerFunctionInvoker funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: No seu DataSnap já está com a função do get pronta?... pois para acessar as funções do DataSnap tem uma nomenclatura, por exemplo: IP:porta/datasnap/rest/TServerMethods1/metodo da sua função no datasnap, pois quando você preencher usuário e senha e entrar, você vai requisitar essa função para poder validar, senão vai dar problema com comunicação.

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf Sim, como disse na pergunta, se testo a URL diretamente pelo navegador funciona normalmente. Tenho outros DataSnaps que funcionam com AJAX normalmente, porem não utilizam autenticação

Comment: Você passa o usuário e a senha para o Datasnap e quer que o mesmo autentique e retorne se deu tudo certo?... se for isso, você vai começar a trabalhar com Headers que são os cabeçalhos, você manda usuário e senha para o DataSnap poder autenticar. Você usa alguma aplicação para poder fazer os testes de requisição, se não usa, sugiro você usar o Postman que é muito bom para testes.

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf Editei a pergunta adicionando um exemplo de algo a mais que tentei.

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma, na classe `ServerMethodsUnit1` que é criada junto quando você cria o **DataSnap REST** adicione no uses da classe `Web.HTTPApp`. Na função que é requisitada quando você passa o usuário e senha, você deve pegar o usuário e a senha que vem do `Header`, então você deve implementar do seguinte modo para conseguir pegar essas informações.

```
var
  oWebModule: TWebModule;
  sBody: String;
begin
  oWebModule := GetDataSnapWebModule;
  sBody := oWebModule.Request.Content;
end;
```

Assim você consegue pegar o `Header` enviado para o **DataSnap**, como você está trabalhando com **REST** por padrão o **LyfeCycle** dele é **Invocation**, A cada execução de um servermethod uma instância da classe será criada e logo depois destruída.
Desse jeito você não consegue trabalhar com sessão, somente se você criar o projeto a partir do DataSnap Server, mas o mesmo não possui o WebBroker para poder pegar o **Header** enviado para o DataSnap.

Comment: Não entendi o motivo de pegar o `Header` na classe `ServerMethodsUnit1 `. Já estou verificando as credenciais enviadas  no `WebModule` no método `OnAuthentication` onde seto o `UserRoles` e atribuo acesso aos métodos na classe `ServerMethodsUnit1 ` por ele.

Comment: O evento onAuthentication é bom para usar quando se controla a sessão do WebService, quais as funções que ele pode ter autorização para acessar, mas se você quer somente autenticar e ver se o usuário está certo. Vou te passar dois links como exemplo, me ajudaram bastante.

https://edn.embarcadero.com/br/article/41267
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Authentication_and_Authorization

Comment: Utilizei estes links como exemplo para construir essa aplicação. Está exatamente da mesma maneira. O que não entendi em sua resposta é o que mais tem após esse código e qual é a funcão `GetDataSnapWebModule`

Comment: É usado para pegar o Header, que seriam o usuário e senha, mas não consegue controlar as autorizações da função.

Comment: @henriqueromao, é uma função nativa do DataSnap, esqueci de mencionar que deve declarar no uses Datasnap.DSHTTPWebBroker para poder usar a função.